# App engine MySQL connection to remote db failing

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

I've got an app engine running and I'm struggling to get the MySQL to connect when it has been deployed. It connects fine on my pc running the dev server, but as soon as I deploy I get this error:

```
OperationalError: (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)")
```

Could this be because it is not a cloud sql database ? I've fiddled with a few things like firewall rules and dns things but I honestly just don't know where to even start solving this issue. Some research indicated it might be a TCP/IP vs Unix socket issue which does also kind of make sense as I've got another connection to a cloud sql instance which works fine (using a unix socket). It is a python app, any help is appreciated

Comment: In the standard app engine environment (not flexible) you can't connect to mysql instances (or any other external database, like mongodb, for that matter) other than cloud sql. The drivers don't support the way app engine handles socket connections, a feature only available to paid apps. Also many drivers attempt to use the file system, which is read only on appengine and thus throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable billing for your project to use socket connections in appengine..